# 301 redirect an old subdomain to a new domain page

Tags: wordpress, web, subdomain

I've separately (on its own server) designed a new website (in Wordpress) for an existing domain, and I'm trying to set up some 301 redirects prior to pointing to the new site.

The only issue is this: the blog and shop on the old site are subdomains.
1. blog.domain.com
2. shop.domain.com

I want 3) www.domain.com/blog and 4) www.domain.com/shop to point to 1 and 2 respectively.

Using the cPanel, I tried to set up 1&2 on the new website just so I could set up a 301 redirect from those addresses to (3 & 4). When I did this, two folders named 'blog' and 'shop' are created on the file server, which caused the links to break.

Given the above, I'm thinking there's probably a better way to do this.

Can anyone share the best way to go about this please? Thanks so much guys.

C

Comment: I should add that I deleted the subdomains/301 redirects I'd set up and the links remained broken. Renaming the folders the cPanel forced me to create rectified this. So it's clean, but I still need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The htaccess file WordPress creates allows you to create your own folders/files for navigation outside of WP - if the files/folders don't exist then they fall into the WordPress permalinks system.

You should therefore be able to create the redirects in cPanel, or creating your own in the htaccess file plenty of resources on Google for 301's in htaccess.

I didn't know cPanel create folders after creating a redirect, but if you simply remove them everything should work fine.